# Почему нельзя "присоединить" поток std::thread дважды?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, stl, concurrency

Скажем, мы хотим дожидаться одного потока в нескольких других, но по идее не можем этого сделать благодаря такому ограничению (из книги C++ Concurrency in Action):

> При вызове join() очищается вся ассоциированная с потоком память, так
>   что объект std::thread более не связан с завершившимся потоком – он
>   вообще не связан ни с каким потоком. Это значит, что для каждого
>   потока вызвать функцию join() можно только один раз; после первого
>   вызова объект std::thread уже не допускает присоединения, и функция
>   joinable() возвращает false.

Я не понимаю, что значит "очищается вся ассоциированная с потоком память". Ведь у каждого потока свой стек по идее. Они образуют один поток? Один стек накидывается поверх другого, или как?

Comment: каждый стек живет отдельно. Когда менджер потоков переключает потоки, он "поправляет" регистры, что бы у потока был правильный указатель на стек.

Comment: Если вам нужно "присоеденить" поток, то, ИМХО вам нужны не потоки (не только), а корутины. В c++ в стандарте их пока нет (будут в 20-ом стандарте), но есть библиотечные реализации, например в boost

Comment: "присоединить" или "дожидаться" - не очень подходящие выражения для `join`. По сути это операция разрушения потока и всех связанных с ним ресурсов, подобно `free` или `delete`. Соответственно ее нельзя вызывать дважды для оной сущности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть поток, реализованный на OS API. Есть объект `thread`, который этим потоком управляет. `join` ждет, когда поток закончится. Это происходит, когда функция потока выходит. Тогда OS освобождает все ресурсы, выделенные для потока. Главный ресурс это стек, он освобождается.

Кстати, `join` не останавливает поток, а просто ждет, когда он сам закончится.

После этого объект `thread` очищает все свои переменные, связанные с этим, уже не существующим, потоком. Прежде всего, обнуляет `thread handle`. То есть, объект `thread` переходит в состояние, когда он ни с каким потоком не связан. В этом состоянии вызов `join` не допускается.

Хотите дождаться окончания потока, не вызывая `join`, используйте `condition_variable`, устанавливайте его перед выходом функции потока. Или возьмите `thread native handle` и ждите на нем средствами OS (но это не cross-platform).